# Check if a class is a Model in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code in Laravel 5.2 that checks if a given db table name ($what) has its own Model :

```
public function manage($what) {

    $model = Str::studly(Str::singular($what));
    if (!is_subclass_of($model, 'Model')) {
        \App::abort(404);
    }

    /* [... other stuff ...] */
}
```

The problem is that is_subclass_of always fail, also when the model exist and it's a subclass of Model. I suppose it's a namespace problem, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need the full namespace. When I do `get_parent_class()` on one of my models, it returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. So use this instead:

```
$model = 'App\\' . Str::studly(Str::singular($what));
if (!is_subclass_of($model, 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model')) {
```

Comment: Please update your answer adding namespace also to $model, like this:
`$model = 'App\\' . Str::studly(Str::singular($what));`

Comment: why do you need two slashes  for App\\  ?

Comment: Harcoding 'App\\' isn't a great idea - would be better to have the full class name passed in.

Answer (score 42):

You can check if your object is an instance of a model with [`instanceof`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php):

```
$article = new \App\Article();

if ($article instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model) {
```

Comment: It doesn't work, since $model is a string with the class name, not an object. It comes from `Str::studly(Str::singular($what))`

Comment: @g4b0 you're creating string from the object? If so, use the object instead of string.

Comment: No, I'm creating the sting from the db table name

Comment: is_a() is not applicable for the OPs problem, because is_a() takes only a object as first paremeter.

Comment: I use this in $this->assertTrue(). Works perfectly