# PHP Check if $model is instance of one out of many classes

Tags: php, laravel

I want to check if $model is an instance of class A, B or C, but not D. So I have an array like that:

`$relevant_classes = [A, B, C];`

I know I can check with `instance of` if the model is in instance of those classes. But do I now have to loop over the array and ask for each single class, if the model is an instance of it?

I would rather want to do something like `if(in_array($model, $relevant_classes))` that compares the class instance. Is that possible in PHP (Laravel)?

Comment: Did you check this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766734/check-if-a-class-is-a-model-in-laravel-5

Comment: You can implement same interface for those A, B, C, eg interface iE and check instanceof iE

Comment: You can use `get_class()` to get the class name of an object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can call [`get_class()`](http://php.net/get_class) to get the name of the class, so your test would be...

```
$relevant_classes = [A::class, "B", C::class]; // use ::class or the class string

if(in_array(get_class($model), $relevant_classes))
```

Comment: That way the array will have to consist of strings, right?

Comment: Yes, you could create your array with something like `$relevant_classes = [A::class, B::class, C::class];`

Comment: Or you can use `$model::class` from PHP 8.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use interfaces for this. Small example:

```
    <?php

interface iA {
    public function foo();
}

interface iB {
    public function bar();
}

class A implements iA {
    public function foo(){ echo 1; }
}

class B implements iA {
    public function foo(){ echo 2; }
}

class C implements iB {
    public function bar(){ echo 3; }
}

class D implements iA, iB {
    public function foo(){ echo 4; }
    public function bar(){ echo 5; }
}

$classes = [new A, new B, new C, new D];

foreach ($classes as $class) {
    if ($class instanceof iA) {
        $class->foo();
    }
    if ($class instanceof iB) {
        $class->bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using interfaces is an interesting approach as well, but too overload for my case. Thank you though!

Comment: But it could be useful in future, as development goes on, so you dont have to keep name of those clases in some array or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_class($model)` to get the class name of the instance.

If you want to check if `$model` is instance of any specific class then you can check like

```
$model instanceof ModelName
```

that returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: Before down-vote please make comments what is wrong with these methods?

Comment: Because `instanceof` takes care of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Php bulid-in [get_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function should help You